# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Jump Lists

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to see jump lists in Windows Server 2008 R2.  I see the Windows 7 style taskbar, but no jump lists.  I wondered if this was due to lack of Aero Graphics, or just 'by design'.

Comment: Have you installed the 'Desktop Experience' feature?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the idea, but I have added that feature.  I am thinking it's this very old iiyama Vision Master Pro 400 monitor.

Comment: I have now started my Themes and see the Aero Glass, but still have no Jump Lists.  Anyone running R2?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer Right click taskbar, properties. Look for a check box saying:

Store and display recently opened items in the Start Menu and the taskbar.

If you click Customize,  Down at the bottom the jump lists should now say 10, not be greyed out.

Comment: On my machine, these settings are all as described.  Simple Jumplists (i.e. only 'Recent' and 'Pinned' items) work for Windows Explorer and Remote Desktop, and Microsoft Word.  However, they do not work for any other program, including, Putty, Chrome, and basically everything else.